# function name as as input of another function?

Tags: python

I an image processing enginner, and am using Python as a prototyping language.

Most of the time, as I get thousands of images, named "imagen.jpg", n being the increment.

So the main structure of my program may be seen as :

```
def main_IP(imgRoot, stop_ncrement):
  name = update_the_increment(imgRoot, stop_increment)
  img = load_the_image(name)
  out_img = process_image(img)
  displays_images(img, out_img)
  return out_img
```

As you can see it, from one application to another, the only change would be the process_image function.
Is there a way so that the process_image can be inserted as an input?

I would get a generic function, prototyped as :
main_IP(imgRoot, stop_increment, process_image)

Thanks ! 
Julien

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions can be passed around in python just like a string or any other object can.

```
def processImage(...):
    pass

def main_IP(imgRoot, stop_ncrement, process_image):
    name = update_the_increment(imgRoot, stop_increment)
    img = load_the_image(name)
    out_img = process_image(img)
    displays_images(img, out_img)
    return out_img

main_IP('./', 100, processImage)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Finally not so complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in python functions are first-class objects, so you can pass them as parameters just like any other data type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code which demonstrates passing the name of the function you want to call, and also passing a reference to the function you want to call:

```
def A():
    return "A!"

def B():
    return "B!"

def CallByName(funcName):
    return globals()[funcName]()

def CallByReference(func):
    return func()

print CallByName("A")

functionB = B
print CallByReference(functionB)
```